# Django choices non-selected field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to remove the non-selected option from a choices of a model form.

my model field is declared :

```
priority = models.IntegerField( choices=PRIORITIES_CHOICES )
```

my form code is :

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['priority'].required = True;
```

however, the non-selected field doesn't want to go away. (I am talking about the ------ option).

Any idea ?

Comment: i think you can also specify a default, which in this case would be self.fields['priority'].initial = "somevalue" and django will not add an empty option

Comment: Well, it does add the ----- option with an initial value :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['priority'].choices = self.fields['priority'].choices[1:]
```

Comment: It does work, but is there a better was to accomplish that ? It is based on luck (that the first row is the "------").

Comment: That's not luck. It will always be the first option unless you alter it yourself for some reason

Comment: Or maybe they will change it in next django version :) I think it is a valid solution, but I would prefer to do it the "django" way. (if there is any)

Comment: There's no reason it would change. The empty choice is *always* the first choice. It's a UI pattern that's followed nearly universally.

Comment: You can set the default=0 in the model itself, if you don't wish to display the first choice as '-------'

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still wonders how to do this in Django 1.5+, the "Django way":

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['priority'].empty_label = None
```

You can also directly add it in the field declaration (if you manually declare it in the init), next to the queryset, widget, required, etc.